# BackgroundColor does NOT Ignore safeArea even if it's declared

Tags: ios, swiftui

I tried everything I could imagine to do and ask Google and Stack Overflow for a while without solution. The only person that ask a similar question had a solution that did not work for me.

I did declare my background color (GameColor.main) on top of the ZStack with .ignoreSafeArea()

However, it does not ignore them. On the other views like the welcome screen it's working fine, but on this specific one it does not.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GameViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
     ZStack{
        GameColor.main.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                Text(viewModel.questionProgessText)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .padding()
                QuestionView(question: viewModel.currentQuestion)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}
```

Only when I put GameColor.main.ignoreSafeArea outside of the `ZStack{}` it will ignore the safe areas (but then obviously override everything else as well).

I tried:

1. declared color in view and try to use it
2. used Color(.blue) directly
3. used .ignoreSafeArea() in a new line
4. put GameColor.main.ignoreSafeArea() on different places of the view
5. put it outside of the ZStack (This worked that it does ignore the safe Areas however it also than override everything else)
6. Tried to ask AI for help
7. Put it into a NavigationView{}

Comment: Can you show screenshots of what your code currently does, as well as your desired result? Also, show a [mcve].

Comment: It's probably because you have `padding()` on your `ZStack`. Add the padding to the `Stack`

Comment: That solves the Problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Paulw11 replied, the problem was that my ZStack{} had .padding, after removing the .padding from the ZStack and attatch it to the VStack the problem was solved.

Thanks again to Paulw11